# gulp-notify over SSH?

Tags: ssh, gulp, growl

If you are using `gulp-notify` locally, you can use it to notify you on your desktop of various things, such as failed/passed unit tests, or whatever:

```
.pipe(notify({
    title: 'PHPUnit Passed',
    message: 'All tests passed!'
}));
```

If you are accessing a remote server over SSH and running tests this way (not locally), is it possible to somehow configure `gulp-notify` to send the notifications to your desktop?